# taxonomy-term at the automatic creation of url alias of a content path

Tags: path-aliases

In Drupal 7, how i can use the taxonomy-term at the automatic creation of url alias of a content path?

Comment: Can you elaborate on this at all? I'm afraid I couldn't understand what you're asking.

Comment: I have the same problem. How did you resolved it?

Answer (score 2):

Install [Pathauto](http://drupal.org/project/pathauto) and [Token](http://drupal.org/project/token). Pathauto will let you create automatic aliases, and Token will supply the content's taxonomy term as a substitutable value.

Comment: I have both of these. I m asking, because taxonomy tokens work only for taxonomy url, and not for content URLs. Am I right?

Answer (score 0):

By using Pathauto(7.x-1.0) & Token(7.x-1.0-beta7) you can not achieve it at this moment I guess. As I also faced the same problem. 
In my case, I have the following URL patterns in D6 site,
D6 --> [vocab-raw]/[term-raw]/[title-raw]
Now, I suppose you have a fresh D7 installation not an upgrade. So If you have a fresh D7 installation do the following,
Create a field in the Content Type as "Term reference" name it "Category" or so. If you are using a upgraded D7 site from D6 site, it will be automatically done.

Now there is two way to do it. 
1. Use the Dev version of the Token Module so you will be able to use taxonomy/vocabulary token variables. As the docs suggests, 

http://drupal.org/node/741914#comment-4006696 

http://drupal.org/node/741914#comment-3714746

But I have used it and haven't got the Success. 
2. So, the next one that worked for me is using the [Entity](http://drupal.org/project/entity) Module.
Install and enable the Module and then do the following,
Go to URL Aliases administration page -> Patterns. Expand replacement patterns for Content paths -> expand Nodes -> you'll see category at the bottom, expand it. OK, now you're ready to use taxonomy terms tokens. 
I am attaching an image for reference.
[image: Vocab]